# framework similar to spring sleuth in python

Tags: python, django, spring, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have recently used spring sleuth framework in my project where all the microservices were in spring boot. I really liked the way distributed logging is being done using spring-sleuth. I would like to know if there is any similar framework available in python + Django framework. I could find opentracing framework.

https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-python

any suggestions will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to google `python tracing Zipkin` - example https://github.com/tryfer/tryfer